# Dynamic Rendering vs Hybrid Rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I watched [Google's conference on SEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFwUbgvpdaQ&t=137) and they talk about Dynamic and Hybrid Rendering. But, I could not understand the difference, what is?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Both of them are methods to improving SEO by complementing the lack of handling heavy JavaScript of search engine bots.

**1. Dynamic Rendering**

*This is a workaround method to improving SEO.*
***It just delivery static html content to crawler(robot) and stay everything the same for the users.***

Dynamic rendering is to detect crawlers (by checking the user agent) and give them a static html content without any JavaScript which is fully-rendered by headless browser like [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer). You may need to host a rendering server like [Rendertron](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron) to deal with the rendering process described above.

**Advantage**

- It didn't rely on changing your current front-end architecture. You don't need to change your code structure to build such as Server-Side Rendering structure or make your site as a static html by adopting Prerendering.
- It's suitable for large and rapidly changing sites.

It also mentioned in this session [Youtube: Deliver search-friendly JavaScript-powered websites (Google I/O '18)](https://youtu.be/PFwUbgvpdaQ?t=1399)

-

**2. Hybrid Rendering**

*This is a long-term recommendation for google search.*

Hybrid Rendering is not a new concept. **It means you ship a part of content (which you want it to be indexed by googlebot) as static html (may generated by template engine or any other way) both to client and bot . And then run JavaScript for showing rest of things such as personalized content**.

It's quit make sense, because we ship main content by static html and providing both wonderful FMP (First Meaningful Painting) for user experience and reduce the burden of Googlebot on consuming resources and times to understand your website. And we still can use powerful JavaScript to build more functionality to your website.

However, it would be a little bit tricky to implementing especially using modern frameworks in some specific and popular architecture. e.g. Single-Page-Application.

You can also check in this session for more information [Youtube: Deliver search-friendly JavaScript-powered websites (Google I/O '18)](https://youtu.be/PFwUbgvpdaQ?t=1177)

-

P.S.
For more detail of the various rendering structure, please check [Rendering on the Web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/rendering-on-the-web). It's an amazing post for those who wants to understand the trade-offs between different structures.

Answer (score -1):

For **Dynamic Rendering**

Google's John Mueller began explaining it a the 21 minute mark into the video. He said "we have a another option [for JavaScript and search] that we'd like to introduce, we call it Dynamic Rendering." He explained "dynamic rendering is the principle of sending normal client-side rendered content to users and sending fully server-side rendered content to search engines and to other crawlers that need it."

Of course, some might call this out as cloaking, but Google said there is a specific policy change for dynamic rendering for this. You serve the server-side rendering to Googlebot and the client-side or hybrid rendering to the user. Here is John's slide on that:

Tools to help you set it up are from Puppeteer and Rendertron.

Google says you should use dynamic rendering when the site is large and changing rapidly, when it uses modern JavaScript features supported in Chrome 41 or above and sites that have strong social media presences should also consider using it:

I don't know much more outside that Google will share more information about this in the future.

For **Hybrid Rendering**

I am posting what I have knowledge about.
If you think of Hybrid Rendering, the first thing comes in mind is V-Ray.

Let’s consider a few use cases for V-Ray Hybrid

Maximize your computing power

If you have a powerful workstation, say 40 CPU cores and 4 GPUs, you can take advantage of all its computing power. Nothing is left idle.

Use all your render nodes

Many artists and studios have GPU & CPU workstations and CPU render nodes. With V-Ray Hybrid they can render using all the hardware they have.

CPU fallback

In case your scene won’t fit into your GPU RAM limits, you can still render on CPU.

Upgrade to GPUs as you go

As CPU machines are ready to be replaced, V-Ray Hybrid can help ease the transition to more GPU rendering, while continuing to take advantage of existing CPU resources. Additionally, if there is an empty PCIe slot on a workstation or render node, adding a GPU can give it a radical speed boost without replacing the whole machine

Comment: Hybrid Rendering has nothing to do with V-Ray, GPU/CPU or other resources. Hybrid rendering for websites is using a combination of server-side and client side rendering, where you first render certain parts of the site on the server, and then add event handlers, update contents to/hydrate/rehydrate the page with JavaScript that's ran on the client.